# Removing every 2nd element in array list

Tags: java

I've been trying so far to write a method ,removeEvenLength that takes an ArrayList of Strings as a parameter and that removes all of the strings of even length from the list. But so far I've been getting a IndexOutOfBoundsException and I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeEvenLength(ArrayList<String> list) {
int size = list.size();
ArrayList<String> newLst = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if (list.get(x).length() % 2 == 0) {
        list.remove(x);
    }
}

return list;
```

}

Comment: Your title does not denote the problem

Comment: Did you try to use Google?

Comment: You need to use an iterator if you want to remove while iterating.

Comment: Also, your method return type, and the presence of newLst, shows that you in fact want to create and return a filtered copy of the original list. So you don't even need to remove anything.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no, that's no what the OP wants to achieve (although the title says so)

Comment: @JBNizet Oops. `return list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() % 2 != 0).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove an element, the size of the list reduces by one and hence the variable `size` no longer denotes the true size of the list

Also, after you remove a String at index `i`, the elements from `i+1, i+2.. list.size() - 1` will be moved to the left by one position. So, incrementing the loop counter `x` all the time is wrong and you will skip some elements.

Here's a way to do it right

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.size();) {
    if (list.get(x).length() % 2 == 0) {
        list.remove(x);
    } else {
        x++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> removeEvenLength(List<String> list) { 
 List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
 for (String item: list) { 
       if (item.length % 2 != 0) {
             newList.add(item); 
        }
  }
 return newList;
}
```

Comment: You cannot remove an item from the list when using the implicit iterator

Comment: For real? Are you going to downvote my answer for no reason?

Comment: I have already told you the reason I guess

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: See, I downvoted for the [first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2cfbefc6-b268-4449-9a13-7a176114d6a0/view-source) of your answer. And you didn't mention that you have edited it afterwards